# Where is my segmentation fault?

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I've got code that compiles well enough, but when I try to run it, I get a segmentation fault and I can't figure out what's wrong.

The point of the program is to piece together the text of fragmentet ascii art files of varying dimensions and number of fragments.
The fragments are named part_xx-yy where xx is from 00 to 11 and yy is from 00 to 05.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


int main(void)
{
    int width;
    int height;
    int xPieces;
    int yPieces;
    int xTens=0;
    int xOnes=0;
    int yTens=0;
    int yOnes=0;
    printf("Fragment width: ");
    scanf("%d", &width);
    printf("Fragment height: ");
    scanf("%d", &height);
    printf("Number of fragments on x axis: ");
    scanf("%d", &xPieces);
    printf("Number of fragments on y axis: ");
    scanf("%d", &yPieces);
    printf("wtf0");
    char *line=malloc(sizeof(width) * sizeof(char));
    printf("wtf1");
    char array[xPieces][yPieces][height][width];
    printf("wtf2");
    char fileName[50];
    printf("wtf3");
    for(int x = 0; x<xPieces;)
    {
        printf("%d", x);
        for(int y = 0; y<yPieces;)
        {
            printf("%d", y);
            if(xOnes>=10) 
            {
                xOnes=0;
                xTens++;
            }
            if(yOnes>=10)
            {
                yOnes=0;
                yTens++;
            }
            snprintf(fileName, sizeof fileName, "part_%i%i-%i%i", xTens, xOnes, yTens, yOnes);
            FILE *file=fopen(fileName, "r");
            char buffer[(width) * (height)];
            fread(buffer, 1, (width) * (height), file);
            for(int i = 0; i<height; i++)
            {
                printf("%d", i);
                for(int j = 0; j<width; j++)
                {
                    printf("%d", j);
                    array[x][y][i][j] = buffer[j + (i * (width))];
                }
            }
            fclose(file);
            y++;
            yOnes++;
        }
        x++;
        xOnes++;
    }

    FILE *newFile=fopen("newFile", "w");

    for(int y = 0; y<yPieces; y++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<height; i++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x<xPieces; x++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j<width; j++)
                {
                    fwrite(&array[x][y][i][j], 1, 1, newFile);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(newFile);
    free(line);
}
```

I figured out how to use the debugger, and that indicated there was something wrong with fread(), which I think was caused by my fileName array, but I changed a few things and now all I get from the debugger is this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0018d68c in fread () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
```

I thought perhaps fread() tried to read into a too small buffer, so I increased the buffer to 10000 (which SHOULD be dramatic overkill), but alas, to no avail.
I have researched quite a bit now, struggling with this problem for a couple of hours, but still have no idea how to go further from here as what I find of similar problems doesn't make much sense to me or isn't similar enough.

I think at this point I need someone else to look at my code, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

.

.

**Update:** I've updated my code with a few changes, and now I get a segmentation fault here instead:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08049058 in main () at innlev3.c:50
50                      *array[x][y][i][j] = buffer[j + (i * (*width))];
```

I thought this part was pretty good... What have I done wrong, here?

**Update 2:** Code updated again. I've found something I think is very strange... Neither of those printf's after my scanf's work... Aand I'm back to the good old fread() segmentation fault. I guess it's a good thing I didn't make a new question out of this... :P

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0018d68c in fread () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x0018d68c in fread () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#1  0x08048fc6 in main ()
```

Comment: You should ask your debugger this type of questions.

Comment: I have updated with a new segmentation fault. Is this ok or should I make a new question?

Comment: I'd say this was enough different to be a separate question, but I doubt the Stack Overflow police will come knocking. ;-) I've had a go at answering your new question, below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing `file` is `NULL`, probably indicating that `*fileName` doesn't exist.

Note that statements like this:

```
fileName[5] = "%i",xTens;
```

don't do what you probably expected. That statement is equivalent to:

```
fileName[5] = xTens;
```

And that should have given you a compiler warning, since you're assigning an `int` to a `char*`.

Instead, you probably meant to use `snprintf` to use `printf`-style formatting to construct the filename.

```
char filename[50];
snprintf(filename, sizeof filename, "part_%i%i-%i%", xTens, xOnes, yTens, yOnes);
FILE *file=fopen(fileName, "r");
```

---

For your second crash: You have an extra layer of pointers that you don't need on `array`. Declare it as `char array...` and remove the `*` when you access it. As it stands now, you've told the compiler that the elements will be pointers, but you haven't made them point anywhere, and then you asked the compiler to go look where they're pointing using `*`. Boom!

Your final use of `array` then needs to make a pointer to each character to pass to `fwrite`. You'd do that with the `&` operator, called "address-of", used like `&array...`.

The address-of operator is the opposite of `*`. Once you have the program working, you can use `&` other places to simplify your code. For example, instead of declaring `int *width` and allocating it off the heap using `malloc`, you can remove the `*` everywhere and pass `&width` to `scanf`.

---

Since we're back to the `fread` segfault: Check the return value of `fopen` before you use it. If it's `NULL`, print an error message.

```
if(file == NULL)
{
    printf("can't open %s\n", fileName);
    exit(1);
}
```

That will probably tell you what's wrong. However, this isn't debugging code. You should generally check for error returns from the functions you call.

Comment: Ahh, I see. That got me past the fread() segfault, but now I've got another one here:

    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    0x08049058 in main () at innlev3.c:50
    50      *array[x][y][i][j] = buffer[j + (i * (*width))];

Comment: Ahh, I was already on to some of this. Good to know I'm getting a better grasp of these pointers. :)
I'm back to the old fread() segmentation fault now, and I found a curiosity: none of the printf("wtf's that I added, prints... Code is updated and your help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: Your `printf` calls are working, but because you didn't add a newline "\n" at the end of them, their output is buffered until you do print a newline.

Comment: I had no idea I had to do that, actually... :P
And yes, your suggestion DID tell me what was wrong. How did I miss the fact that I was trying to open a file I didn't have. Haha. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't setting *width to anything before you use it.

You want to do your allocation after you have read the sizes.

```
printf("fragment width: ");
scanf("%i", width);
printf("fragment height: ");
scanf("%i", height);
char *line=malloc(sizeof(*width) * sizeof(char));
```

Also, this isn't doing what you think it is:

```
        FILE *file=fopen(*fileName, "r");
```

It is going to open a file called "p".

And this doesn't do what you think it does either:

```
        fileName[5] = "%i",xTens;
```

I think you are thinking of python.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be true--there's a `scanf` that should set `*width`.

Comment: @JameySharp: but the scanf was done after *width was used.

Comment: Ah, I see your point--but then the variable `line` that's allocated using the uninitialized `width` is not used anywhere, and the crash doesn't occur there, but occurs later instead.

Comment: I changed the code according to your suggestion, and have also made some changes to my code according to another suggestion, so I am getting a new segmentation fault now.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `gdb` and backtrace you see this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a8a724 in fread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007ffff7a8a724 in fread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000000000400ad1 in main ()
```

it means that you are crashing in `fread`. Your file variable in `fread()` seems to be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the backtrace tip. I will use that in the future. :)
For now, the new segmentation fault I have after updating my code only gives me the same thing if I do a simple backtrace, and I don't see what's wrong with my code here either.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for learning to use the debugger :)  You're not checking the return value of "fopen".  What value of `file` is being passed to `fread`?