# locate where in libc my segfault occurs

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, libc

My C program crashed on CentOS 5.7 with the following log:

```
kernel: [1030648.130682] myapp[16454]: segfault at 0 ip b765f683 sp bfc3fa0c error 4 in libc-2.5.so[b75ee000+157000]
```

Seems a call to libc caused the segfault. How can I know in which function in libc the segfault happened?

It's a prod environment and no coredump file was left; and it rarely reproduces. So, what I can do now is to analyze which function in libc (called by my program) caused this segfault, then I can check my code.

It'll be great if there are pointers that explain what these numbers mean: ip b765f683, sp bfc3fa0c, error 4, b75ee000+157000. I googled but didn't find good references.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried googling with your title? http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbsegfault.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337472/where-is-my-segmentation-fault

Comment: That's why we compile with the `-g` flag, and [use tools like gdb](http://www.centos.org/docs/3/html/rhel-devtools-en-3/s1-gdb-debugging.html): so we can work it out ourselves, and not use a Q&A site as an interactive debugger

Comment: sorry I didn't mean to use this site as an interactive debugger. My problem is that, the sgefault happened at a prod environment and no coredump file was left; and it rarely reproduces so using gdb to see where it happens doesn't work (since it doesn't crash a lot). So, what I can do now is to analyze which function in libc (called by my program) caused this segfault, then I can check my code.

It'll be great if there are pointers that explain what these numbers mean: ip b765f683, sp bfc3fa0c, error 4, b75ee000+157000. I googled but didn't find good references.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interpreting segfault messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549214/interpreting-segfault-messages)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, segmentation fault is a sign that your application is trying to access some unauthorized/unintedneded memory region. Compile your code with `-g` switch, then run the generated binary with some memory debugger like [valgrind](/questions/tagged/valgrind) and check what is the output from [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Most of the times, you'll get the erroneous call which caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

Compile using `-ggdb` switch (using gcc) and use `gdb` to find out where is the source of the crash ... This [tutorial](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/) is very helpful.